# Dual boot. Windows about to expire!

Tags: dual-boot

So basically I had a dual boot laptop, with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 Pro. So I had the Windows download from another source, I thought it was activated, but it's not. So now it's gonna be expired soon, I have a lot of files in it , but I use only Ubuntu all the time. So I use all windows just to install stuffs, because i had mistakenly partitioned it more. So all files are in my Windows and I use those files directly from Ubuntu OS. So what will happen if windows expire? Will all my files go? Or is there anything I can do to transfer all my data from Windows to Linux? Or is there any safe way to delete Windows manually without affecting any files? 
PS: Need ways without the use of External hard drive

Comment: It is really not an Ubuntu question what Windows does when it expires.  I suspect it does nothing to your files.  I know it cannot do anything to your files if you do not run it.

Comment: That's because you don't have legit copy of windows. Windows isn't free, you should have considered buying a copy. This might help https://www.thewindowsclub.com/what-happens-when-windows-10-expires

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows partition will continue to work as an NTFS partition even after Windows license expires. If you wish, you can continue to use the partition just like that.

Alternately, you could take a back-up and then shrink / delete the partition. Since you mentioned that your Windows partition is large, I suspect you'll have to do this in multiple iterations. So, you should try mounting the Windows partition and then copy your files to Linux/Ubuntu/other partition. Then shrink Windows partition (which may cause data loss), and expand other partition, and repeat the copying. Since you don't want to use a LiveUSB, the expansion has to be a fresh partition, because as pointed out by Kulfy, you can't change Linux OS partition when you're booted from that partition.

Comment: you might like to add that you can't shrunk or extend partitions in Ubuntu if Ubuntu is currently booted. You need to have a live USB.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: `So what will happen if windows expire? Will all my files go?`
Nothing will happen to your files. You can continue using your files as such from Ubuntu. 
Also, you can use the files from Windows too with just message on right bottom corner, saying `Activate Windows \n Go to PC Settings to activate Windows`. You can read further [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/what-happens-if-you-do-not-activate-windows-10/129724c0-2a42-4d96-8522-9092c91f5ae9).